# SelfHosting ApiController, how to return errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, owin, self-hosting

I've used [examples like this](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-controller) to create a selfhosting API controller. It can `HttpPost` and `HttpGet` a `Customer` object.

The (simplified) function to get a `Customer` by Id is :

```
[RoutePrefix("test")]
public class MyTestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("getcustomer")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Customer GetCustomer(int customerId)
    {    // as a test: react as if this customer exists:
         return new Customer()
         {
              Id = customerId,
              Name = "John Doe",
         };     
    }
    ...
}
```

This works fine. On my Client side I can ask this test server for a customer by Id and I get a Customer with the expected data.

Apparently the calling function knows how to wrap my returned Customer into an object (`HttpResponseMessage`?) that can be transferred to my client.

**Next step: return error 404 if the customer is not found.**

```
[Route("getcustomer")]
[HttpGet]
public Customer GetCustomer(int customerId)
{    // as a test: only customer 1 exists
     if (customerId == 1)
     {
         return new Customer()
         {
              Id = customerId,
              Name = "John Doe",
         };   
      }
      else
      {
           // TODO: make sure 404 Err not found returned.
      }
}
```

How to do this? Throw an exception? Call one of the WebApi functions to inform that error 404 should be returned instead of my returned Customer?

Answer (score 8):

Return an `IHttpActionResult` instead:

```
[Route("getcustomer")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer(int customerId)
{    // as a test: only customer 1 exists
    if (customerId == 1)
    {
        return Ok(new Customer()
        {
            Id = customerId,
            Name = "John Doe",
        });
    }

    // TODO: make sure 404 Err not found returned.
    return NotFound();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the return value to an IHttpActionResult and return either [System.Web.Http.Results.OkResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.results.okresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [System.Web.Http.Results.NotFoundResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.results.notfoundresult(v=vs.118).aspx)

However, an easier solution that is similar to what you would normally do, is to throw a [System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpresponseexception(v=vs.118).aspx).

The constructor takes a [System.Net.HttpStatusCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.118).aspx). The exception is catched by your caller and translated into the corresponding response.

```
[Route("getcustomer")]
[HttpGet]
public Customer GetCustomer(int customerId)
{    // as a test: only customer 1 exists
    if (customerId == 1)
    {

    };   
    else
    {
       throw new HttpResponseException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```